# Quick action from Visualforce Page loaded in Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, object, action

I want to call an object action to create/update a record from visualforce Page that is loaded in Lightning Experience within a Lightning I-frame.

I tried the following but it gives error, what am I missing?

```
 <apex:commandButton value="Create Account" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.CreateAccount)}"/>
```

Comment: in lightning url hack is not allowed...

Comment: I'm understanding the question a bit differently then the URL hack, since you can predefine fields in quick actions is it possible to have the quick action buttons on the visualforce page. Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes jenny. I want to call the quick action to update a record from visualforce page. The above syntax is not working. Is it possible to call quick action through controller or Vf page?

Comment: What is the error you're getting ?